# Display a Backbone collection with HTML formatting

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone.js-collections

I have a Marionette CollectionView displaying some data from a collection. It's all working fine BUT some items in my collection has HTML tags.

To make it easier, here is only two items:

```
var topics = [
  { content: 'This is a <strong>bold</strong> content' },
  { content: 'This is a <i>italic</i> content' }
];
```

On screen is being displayed:

> `This is a <strong>bold</strong> content`
>
> `This is a <i>italic</i> content`

instead of

> This is a **bold** content
>
> This is a *italic* content

There is some Marionette native attribute to allow HTML formatting or should I write a function to convert the HTML entities?
Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Underscore/JS templates, you just need to make sure you are interpolating the values (using `<%=`):

```
<div><%= content %></div>
```

vs HTML-escaping:

```
<div><%- content %></div>
```

The following fiddle shows a more complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/8m7ot074/

If you are using handlebars to handle your templating, you'd need to use the 'triple-stache': `{{{content}}}`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.